# PHP code structure for string manipulation tasks

Tags: php, strings

I need to perform a bunch of string manipulation tasks on an original string, then output the final string. Best I could think of is extracting some functionality into functions. Any better way to structure it? Also, are the variable/function names too long?

- strip out unicode chars from original string A, reverse them into string B
- in the remaining string A, remove duplicate words
- append: A + B

```
function extract_unicode_characters_from_string($str) {
    preg_match_all('/\p{Han}+/u', $str, $unicode_characters_only, PREG_SET_ORDER);
    $squashed = array_column($unicode_characters_only, 0);
    return $squashed;  
}

function strip_unicode_characters_from_string($str) {
    return preg_replace('/\p{Han}+/u', '', $str);
}

function strip_duplicates($str){
    $exploded_str = explode(' ', $str);
    $exploded_str_no_empties = array_filter($exploded_str, function($item) { return !is_null($item) && $item !== ''; });
    return implode(' ', array_unique($exploded_str_no_empties));
}

$original_string = 'one two three 喞 喝 four 刷囿 two 跏正 吁';

$array_of_unicode_characters = extract_unicode_characters_from_string($original_string);
$reversed_unicode_characters = implode(' ', array_reverse($array_of_unicode_characters));

$string_without_unicode_characters = strip_unicode_characters_from_string($original_string);
$english_words_no_dupes = strip_duplicates($string_without_unicode_characters);

echo $english_words_no_dupes . ' ' . $reversed_unicode_characters;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think your variable names are a bit long.  While it is good to be expressive, you don't want to be pushing your line width beyond the recommended max width if avoidable.

I don't know if you need many custom functions here.  The shared calls which filter empty and duplicate strings can be a custom call.  Otherwise, everything else is single-use.

Consider this snippet which simplifies much of the script by grouping the multibyte and single-byte non-whitespace substrings from the start.  No extra exploding, and only one implode call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/99NV4))

```
function uniqueNoEmpty($array) {
    return array_unique(array_filter($array, 'strlen'));
}

$original_string = 'one two three 喞 喝 four 刷囿 two 跏正 吁';

if (!preg_match_all('~(\p{Han}+)|(\S+)~u', $original_string, $out)) {
    echo 'no qualifying strings';
} else {
    $singleBytes = uniqueNoEmpty($out[2]) ?? [];
    $multiBytes = array_reverse(uniqueNoEmpty($out[1]));

    echo implode(' ', array_merge($singleBytes, $multiBytes));
}
```